# How to create a HDR file from set of image files?

Tags: 12.04, jpeg

I have many JPEG image files for the same scene with different exposure setting. How to create HDR file using them in Ubuntu 12.04amd64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Luminance HDR.

[image]

**Supported features**

- Create an HDR file from a set of images (formats: JPEG, TIFF 8bit and
  16bit, RAW) of the same scene taken at different exposure setting;
- Save load HDR images;
- Rotate, resize and crop HDR images;
- Tonemap HDR images;
- Copy exif data between sets of images;
- Supports internationalization.
  [image]

Tnstall Luminance HDR in ubuntu

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:dhor/myway
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install luminance-hdr
```

[Source](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/luminance-hdr-application-for-high-dynamic-range-hdr-imaging.html) and [more information](http://qtpfsgui.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the package enfuse:

```
sudo apt-get install enfuse
```

Then change to the directory with the photos:

```
cd ~/Photos/HDRstack
enfuse -o result.jpg --exposure-weight=1 --saturation-weight=0 --contrast-weight=0 --hard-mask *.jpg
gimp result.jpg
```

Find out about more options:

```
man enfuse
```